# Better way to update ComboBox dynamically?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, combobox, visual-studio-2013

I was wondering if anyone had a suggestion or tip to improve the following function of my code. Basically I'm making a Update/Modify Form which fills its fields from a table of a DataBase, everything so far works great until I arrive at the comboboxes.

I have three of them, role, status and gender. The problem is that when I loaded the current user's information like this:

```
    Dim lstDatos As New ArrayList()
    lstDatos = gestorUsuario.consultarUsuario(idUsuario)

    txtNombre1.Text = lstDatos(0)
    txtNombre2.Text = lstDatos(1)
    txtApellido1.Text = lstDatos(2)
    txtApellido2.Text = lstDatos(3)
    cmbGenero.DisplayMember = lstDatos(4)  'HERE
    txtCorreo.Text = lstDatos(5)
    txtCedula.Text = lstDatos(6)
    txtTelefono.Text = lstDatos(7)
    cmbRol.Text = lstDatos(8)        'HERE
    cmbEstado.Text = lstDatos(9)     'And Here
```

Only the user's current Rol, Estado and Gender could be selected, to workaround that I made the following:

```
Private Sub updateRol(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbRol.Click

    actualizarComboBox()

End Sub
```

Which calls the actualizarFunction:

```
Private Sub actualizarComboBox()

    cmbGenero.Items.Add("Masculino")
    cmbGenero.Items.Add("Femenino")

    cmbEstado.DataSource = gestorUsuario.consultarEstados
    cmbEstado.DisplayMember = "nombre_estado"
    cmbEstado.ValueMember = "id_estado"

    cmbRol.DataSource = gestorRol.consultarRoles
    cmbRol.DisplayMember = "nombre"
    cmbRol.ValueMember = "id_rol"

End Sub
```

It kinda works to be honest but...the first time the comboBox is selected you can see a visible jump when it loads the other options, also when I click the combo it automatically loses the "placeholder" if you will, of the user's current information and goes right up to the first option.

So if I have:

*B

As my user's current `cmbRol.Text` and I click the ComboBox it flickers a bit and changes to:

*A
-B
-C

Where * represent the selected or highlighted option.
If anyone had any suggestions or tips I would be very grateful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In fact, you need to call your `actualizarComboBox()` upon FormLoad(), then you can set the value to current option

Comment: @Nadeem_MK But if I do that and I don't want to change that user's rol or gender etc I will have to reassign him/her those options each time I save other field.

Comment: Ohh meaning the gendre might be left blank? In this case, you can still add a generic value as the first item in your list, such as '_Choose an option_' sort of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
 cmbGenero.DisplayMember = lstDatos(4)  'HERE
 cmbRol.Text = lstDatos(8)        'HERE
 cmbEstado.Text = lstDatos(9)     'And Here
```

for this:

```
cmbGenero.SelectedItem = lstDatos(4) 'SelectedItem is sufficient because cmbGenero is not binding to Data Base
cmbRol.SelectedValue = lstDatos(8)   'SelectedValue is required because cmbRol and cmbEstado is binding to Data Base
cmbEstado.SelectedValue = lstDatos(9)
```